# Using a remote Plist

Tags: ios, swift, plist

My app currently uses a Plist to display items in a TableView. The Plist resides inside the Bundle resources of the app. But now I want to be able to fetch the same PList from the web so I can update it anytime.

My current code:

```
func getItems() -> [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]?{
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Items", ofType: "plist", 
        let itemsDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path),
        let items = itemsDictionary["biology"] as? [String:AnyObject]
    {
        return items["biology"] as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

How could I implement a "downloadable" solution to retrieve the same Plist?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of overkill to import a whole dependency to solve a single issue, assuming you have no other networking needs in your app, but [Alamofire](https://github.com/alamofire/alamofire) has a plist decoder built in. It would be as simple as:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://yourserver.com").responsePropertyList { (request, response, result, error) in

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A plist is just XML so parsing it will work the same. You'll just want to do a fetch with NSURLSession or NSURlConnection. Once you get a response you'll serialize that response into a NSDictionary with NSPropertyListSerialization.

Here is an old Obj-C I found that should do the trick. Translating it into Swift won't be hard

```
NSURL *url = [NSURLURLWithString:@"http://lab.vpgroup.com.br/aplicativos/teste-catalogo/lista.plist"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,    NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
NSDictionary *dict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data mutabilityOption:0 format:0 errorDescription:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
}];
```

Comment: What if I have to get details from a remote plist thats there in the directory of the server ? The details like serverName, serverPort, UDID and few other userdefaults are initialised in the installprofile.plist.. and I want to access them .. Is there any possible way to download it ? inside the xml , the details are mentioned as a seperate <dict> as configurations. Please help.

Comment: In my example above I'm serializing the plist into an NSDictionary so you should be able to just access the the plist keys in the dictionary as normal

Comment: the problem is the url keeps changing from client to client and so i cannot download the plist and i want to get the servername, serverport, udid and other details from the plist that is being sent with the app when it is pushed from a mdm server .